# "undefined is not a function" error when using mongoose-sessions and express

Tags: express, mongoose, runtime-error

When I init the application everything is ok, but when I go to any page
like "localhost/" I get this (double: once for the index.html and once for the javascript requested, see bellow) error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at hash (myapp\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:341:10)
    at myapp\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:324:24
    at Promise.module.exports.SessionStore.get (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\index.js:85:22)
    at Promise.addBack (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:66:38)
    at Promise.complete (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:77:20)
    at Query.findOne (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1607:15)
    at model.Document.init (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:229:11)
    at model.init (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:196:36)
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at hash (myapp\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:341:10)
    at myapp\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\session.js:324:24
    at Promise.module.exports.SessionStore.get (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\index.js:85:22)
    at Promise.addBack (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:66:38)
    at Promise.complete (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:77:20)
    at Query.findOne (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1607:15)
    at model.Document.init (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:229:11)
    at model.init (myapp\node_modules\session-mongoose\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:196:36)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = this.__app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
     store: this.__getSessionStore()
    ,secret: this.__secretSession
}));

app.post('/rpc', this.__manageRequest.bind(this)); // <-- this method is not even called
app.use("/client", express.static('./client/')); // 
// gets the index.html, but files in subfolders (which exists) throws the second error in the double error 
app.use("/", express.static('./client/production/build')); 

app.listen(this.__appPort, this.__appIp);
```

How I get the session store:

```
__getSessionStore: function(){
    var express = require('express');
    var app = this.__app;
    var SessionMongoose = require("session-mongoose")(express);
    var mongooseSessionStore = new SessionMongoose({
         url: this.__mongodbUrl
        ,interval: 120000
    });
    return mongooseSessionStore;
}
```

Express version: 3.0.0
Mongoose-sessions version: 0.2.0

The undefined method is "crc16" in the hash method: in debug is undefined too

```
function hash(sess) {
  return crc16(JSON.stringify(sess, function(key, val){
    if ('cookie' != key) return val;
  }));
}
```

In the crc module, there is a if(window) and window is defined, the problem is that I cannot see where it's defined!
Because of this window, it will not export any of the modules and therefore the function is undefined! I just very hackly removed the if(window) to always export to it's module.
Well, that was a bug in the crc@0.2.0 module (https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-crc/pull/10), and the express is requiring that exact version.

What exactly is the problem and how to fix it?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**This only worked the first time, then BUM, same error again...**

As the dependencies in the session-mongoose are like this (loosely):

```
"dependencies": {
  "mongoose": ">= 3.0"
},
```

It downloaded the mongoose 3.5.4! Npm should only have downloaded the 3.0, but I don't know what happened.

Now I deleted that and put the mongoose at the same version as in my app: 3.4.0.

I still don't know what's wrong with the 3.5.4 version or if the problem is not being equal, but here is the fix.

So many time lost because of this... :S

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps edit ./node_modules/express/package.json to tell it to use more recent CRC library.

Change the line:

```
"crc": "0.2.0",
```

to

```
"crc": ">= 0.2.0",
```

and then run

```
npm install -d
```

If that doesn't install an updated crc library, manually delete the folder ./node_modules/express/node_modules/crc and try again.

I don't promise this will work but it is worth a shot!

Comment: well, when the crc author updated the crc module, didn't changed the version, so it's still crc@0.2.0, but there are 2 different versions in one... So have to delete the folder and re-install the crc... Or maybe the crc@0.2.0 in git is different than in npm.. don't know yet, because I directly copied from git.